# How to prove that :$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}}=(-1)^{n-1}\;\;\; n\in\mathbb{N}^*$

Tags: complex-numbers

Can someone tell me how to prove the folowing equalty :
$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}}=(-1)^{n-1}\;\;\; n\in\mathbb{N}^*.$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $\prod_0^{n-1} e^{ak}=e^{a(0+1+2+\cdots +(n-1))}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. If you can comfortably finish from there, you may want to give an answer yourself.

Comment: Take the logarithm of the lhs. The resulting expression is just an arithmetic progression. Compute  it and go back to the exponential.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will answer my question

We have : $$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}}=e^{\frac{2\pi i }{n}\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}=e^{\pi i (n-1)}=\cos((n-1)\pi)=(-1)^{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Consider the polynomial $x^n-1$. Vieta's formula says that $-1=(-1)^n z_1\cdots z_n$ where the $z_i$ are the roots of the polynomial. What are these roots?